# How to check whether main function was called?

Tags: c++, static, program-entry-point, crt

I want to write some code which will depend on a static variable value. So I want to add some check to eliminate the possibility of calling this code from other static variable constructors. And prevent the static initialization order fiasco once and forever. For example:

```
static Foo foo = Foo();

// this function should be called ONLY from main program conrol flow
// ONLY after all static variable initialization was complete! ONLY!
int bar()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
  if(! CRT_was_initialized_and_main_function_was_called ) ShowErrorMessage();
#endif
  if(foo.somefunction() == 2) return 0; else return -1;
}

//here inattentive programmer will caught error message during debug
const int barConstant = bar();

int main()
{
  //now all is fine
  const int barConstant = bar();
}
```

How can I do so? How to check whether my function was called after main function was?

UPDATE: Foo object have a very heavy initialization code, it could be slow and even throw an exception

UPDATE2: There is no life concern to do so. Comment before bar function worked fine most of the time. I interested in some sort of debug check to punish inattentive programmer in debug version of program instead of doing this manually. And it could be nonstandard way like a call to some crazy builtin function which will work only on MSVC.

Comment: If you don't want to verify each time your program executes, you can set up a break point and go into Debug, to see whether the initializations have been made or not.

Comment: In your code the first line is declaring a function, not a class instance.

Comment: I was under the impression that the current paradigm is "static and global state is bad". With problems similar to this one as main reasons why. Is there any chance for refactoring?

Comment: This Foo object are actually very heavy its initialization take a loooong time and could result in an error which shouldn't be thrown during CRT initialization. In contrast bar function should be very light and called in very hot part of codes in loops etc. The only possible refactoring which I see here is to make a Foo a singleton like object... but it it would be trade of only solution.

Comment: Can you grant friendship to `main`?  ideone and cormeau lets me, but I don't have access to an actual compiler/linker so that I can check how it behaves with separate translation units.  You still have the issue that static initialization can occur after you enter `main`, but at least you would know only `main` could create your `Foo` object.

Answer (score 3):

Create a global `bool` flag that indicates whether main was called or not, initially false.
Change it to true inside `main()`, and only change it there. Not an elegant solution, but a solution to a very weird problem, too.

Comment: Most importantly, the cleanest it seems.

Comment: I have no access to main function, I am from different department and working on library. This library has no Initialization function of any sort though.

Comment: @ZAB: I guess you're out of luck then. Ask the other departement if they could add such a flag.

Comment: @Xeo: Yep! But I thought it could be done in debug version, call or check some functions with a huge "_" prefix and strange name like _crtdll_init. Also it would be enough to do this check only on MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

i would go with this function and `mainCalled` is a global boolean variable what is false by default and changed to true whever main is called:

```
int bar()
{
    static bool called = 0;
    if (!mainCalled)
        ShowErrorMessage();
    if (called)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    called = true;
    //do somthing
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you declare an object outside the main function, its constructor will run before `main()`. That can happen if you initialize some global value with an expression that involves a function call. And that may be a problem. A big one, hard to figure out.

Comment: I thought I fixed my answer for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare a global variable `int main_called = 0;` before the function.

In the function you check if the variable is 0 and in main you set the variable to 1.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a portable way to do this. You can of course have your own global that you initialise in main and then uninitialise at the end of main (don't forget to use a constructor/destructor to ensure this works right even when an exception exits main).

On MSVC an easier but non portable way is #prgama init_seg. This gives you three pre-set phases and many more you can create yourself.

Martyn

Comment: You say there isn't a portable way to do this; then you proceed to explain a portable way to do it (global variable in main). :-/

Comment: There isn't a poortable way to check if the CRT was initialised and the startup sequence is completed. The best you can do is check whether you are in main. And of course, nothing stops a portable program from calling main from a static constructor (even though that would be weird and bad).

Comment: All objects marked by #pragma init_seg still will be initialized before main... how to put one on the very end of CRT initialization list?

Comment: If you use init_seg, you don't need to put one at the very end. Instead, simply apply init_seg grouping appropriately to each of your constructors to ensure appropriate orderings by layer.

However, you can get into the end by using your own section names.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a good case for a singleton pattern than can check its own initialization?

Comment: Sort of but this stupid Foo object could throw an exception or slow down program initialization. You cant prevent static objects to instantiate singleton during its own initialization phase.